# How do I open a file in c that is in the same directory as the program?

Tags: c, file-io, network-programming, fopen

Hi everyone I am trying to open a file from a server program that I wrote for my network programming class to send to my client program. I have tried using fopen,

```
  strcat(cwd, msg);              //i append the directory to the filename
  printf("%s\n", cwd);

  if(n>0){
     req = fopen(msg, "r");      //fopen(~\\blah\\blah\\blah\\msg)
```

msg is the name of a txt file.

I want this done in c.

Any ideas? greatly appreciated.

would like to add that req turns out to be null even though the directory printed out is correct.

Comment: `fopen` should be looking for file with names specified in relative path based on the running *environment variable*. If you insist on using "path of the executable file", get it from `args[0]`

Comment: Do you mean "open a file in the current working directory", or do you really mean "in the same directory as the program executable resides"? Your usage of the variable name `cwd` in your sample code seems to suggest the former.

Comment: Sry the naming of the variable is misleading. I infact do want it from  the same directory as the program. I have been initializing a string with the directory containing the file I want but args[0] seems to be the way I want to go.

Comment: If that `~` is meant to expand to your home directory, `fopen()` won't expand it for you.

Comment: how about simple `./` ?

Answer (score 2):

The real answer to your question is that you can't. C provides no way for you to know where the file your program image was constructed from resides, partly because it makes no assumptions that it was even constructed from a file. So there's no generic, portable way that is guaranteed to work.

However, in certain environments and under certain conditions, you can use `argv[0]`, which might contain the path using which the program file was found. This is frequently the case under Unix/Linux (but not necessarily -- you are beholden to the program that started your program). I have no clue how it is on other systems like Windows.

If you want to use that method, you can do something like this:

```
FILE *openrelative(char *base, char *name)
{
    char *buf1, *dir, *buf2;
    int len;
    FILE *ret;

    buf1 = strdup(base); /* dirname might modify its argument, so copy base. */
    dir = dirname(buf1);
    len = strlen(dir) + 1 + strlen(name) + 1;
    buf2 = malloc(len);
    snprintf(buf2, len, "%s/%s", dir, name);
    ret = fopen(buf2, "r");
    free(buf2); free(buf1);
    return(ret);
}
```

Then, call this function from `main` as `openrelative(argv[0], "msg.txt")`. Or from somewhere else, but you need to make `argv[0]` available somehow.

Since these methods aren't guaranteed to work, however, you shouldn't really use them. Especially not if your program is supposed to be portable or used by others.

Comment: On Windows, argv[0] is the same - exe path - on all the C/C++ compilers I have used.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment in the code:

```
// fopen(~\\blah\\blah\\blah\\msg)
```

the variable `cwd` may be `~`. If so, then as FatalError mentions, `fopen()` won't expand it for you.  Only the shell does this, on systems I've used.

The work-around is e.g. to call `getenv("HOME")`, and then expand the `~` yourself.