# How to open a file no matter where I run my program from?

Tags: c, gcc, fopen

`fopen` always tries to load files from the working path. To reproduce the bug, I wrote a demo code below:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE* my_file = NULL;
    const char* file_name = "some_file.dat";
    errno_t errcode = fopen_s(&my_file, file_name, "rb");
    if (errcode != 0) {
        printf("Cannot open the file `%s`. Error code = %d", file_name, errcode);
    }
    else {
        puts("Success!!");
    }
    return errcode;
}
```

1. I have a file `d:\path1\some_file.dat` and a directory `d:\path2`. Then I compile the code above to the program named `D:\path1\myprogram.exe`.
2. Input command

   ```
   cd d:\path1
   myprogram
   ```

   and the program will print "Success!!".
3. Input command

   ```
   cd d:\path2
   ..\path1\myprogram
   ```

   and the program will print "Cannot open the file `some_file.dat`. Error code = 2".

**My question is how to successfully open the file no matter where I run my program from.** If `fopen` can't do this, is there a library that can do it?

Reply to the comments:

I know that `fopen` can load files from absolute paths but I want to make my program portable. `myprogram.exe` and `some_file.dat` are always in the same path.

Comment: You could always ask for the file location if the default way fails.

Comment: You could try looking at `argv[0]` as a basis for the filename.

Comment: A path is called absolute if it indicates a root directory to start from. It is called relative if it does not. Opening a file using an absolute path starts from the root directory the absolute path indicates. Opening a file using a relative path starts from the process’ working directory. `some_file.dat` is a relative path. Change it to an absolute path. Change `const char* file_name = "some_file.dat";` to `const char *file_name = "d:\\path1\\some_file.dat";`.

Comment: your code at the moment is pure C as far as I can tell. Any specific reason why you give it the c++ / visual-c++ tags as well?

Comment: *"I know that fopen can load files from absolute paths but I want to make my program portable."* - how is your program supposed to find the file if you cannot specify an absolute path, nor you know the proper relative path to it? Magically, somehow...?

Comment: Is the file *always in the same directory as your executable*?

Comment: Reply to codeling: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file is in the same folder as the executable.
You can use the `argv[0]` passed to the program – which is the executable name.
I have shown it run three ways: two from the console, and one from GUI file manager.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SLASH_CHAR  '\\'    // Windows
//#define SLASH_CHAR  '/'    // Linux

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const char* file_name = "some_file.dat";    // desired filename
    printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);          // the executable
    
    // allocate enough memory to create a file name
    char *fname = malloc(strlen(argv[0]) + strlen(file_name) + 1);
    if(fname == NULL)
        return 1;

    // find the last path separator in the executable (if any)
    char *slash_ptr = strrchr(argv[0], SLASH_CHAR);
    if (slash_ptr == NULL) {
        // just use the file name
        strcpy(fname, file_name);
    }
    else {
        // create a new file name
        strcpy(fname, argv[0]);
        size_t slash_ind = slash_ptr - argv[0];
        strcpy(fname + slash_ind + 1, file_name);
    }
    
    printf("fname = %s\n", fname);
    free(fname);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Run from the console current directory

```
argv[0] = test
fname = some_file.dat
```

Run in the console from a parallel folder

```
argv[0] = ..\temp\test
fname = ..\temp\some_file.dat
```

Run from Windows file manager

```
argv[0] = F:\TEMP\test.exe
fname = F:\TEMP\some_file.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` can take either a full, **absolute** path to a file, or, if it gets an incomplete path, it has to assume that the path is **relative**; relative paths are always relative to the current working directory.

In short, `fopen`, just as any other facility to open files, cannot magically guess what file you mean; it needs to know exactly where it should look for the file.

You can specify a full path like this:

```
    // ....
    const char* file_name = "D:\\path1\\some_file.dat";
    // ....
```

From your comments, your problem however seems to be that you don't know the exact full path to the file at compile time; so you probably want to get the path to the file from the user of the program somehow;

One typical way of doing this is to read it from a parameter at the command line:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* my_file = NULL;
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("You need to specify a filename!");
        return 2;
    }
    errno_t errcode = fopen_s(&my_file, argv[1], "rb");
    if (errcode != 0) {
        printf("Cannot open the file `%s`. Error code = %d", argv[1], errcode);
    }
    else {
        puts("Success!!");
    }
    return errcode;
}
```

Running:

Test case 1:

```
> cd d:\path1
> myprogram some_file.dat
Success!!
```

Test case 2 (relative):

```
> cd d:\path2
> ..\path1\myprogram ..\path1\some_file.dat
Success!!
```

Test case 2 (absolute):

```
> cd d:\path2
> ..\path1\myprogram d:\path1\some_file.dat
Success!!
```

If your `some_file.dat` always resides in the same folder as your program, there are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024937) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14974578) available on similar questions.

You can also combine a path specified at the command line with a hard-coded file name of course, for that, look into `sprintf` function if you need to stick to C language, or e.g. `std::ostringstream` if you can actually use C++ as your tags suggest.